# VS 2010 output regenerated automatically

Tags: locking

I am using VS 2010 in windows 7 64-bit. It keeps giving me error when I build my project, saying the output is being locked.

I manually delete the output exe and it keeps coming back even though I haven't recompiled the code. What's going on?

Comment: Are you SURE you actually delete it?  Check process monitor to see if your program is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another source of the problem: Application Experience Service. I enabled it and the issue completely disappeared.

Now happy coding again.

Answer (score 0):

This has been the most frustrating problem I've seen and it seems to be related to the ** Windows Search service**. I have to disable it and the problem went away 99% of the time. Occasionally it still came back. I just waited 30 seconds.